# Change String to Date with using date -d

Tags: shell-script, date

I need to change a date String from format YYYYMMDD to date YYYY-MM-DD without using date -d command. The only option I found is string manipulations.

Comment: How many tools can you name that perform text manipulation? If none, please go and do some basic research. Otherwise, tell us what you’ve tried. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  P.S. Technically, you have not asked a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using bash parameter expansion?

```
$ var=20180402
$ echo "${var::4}-${var:4:2}-${var:6}"
2018-04-02
```

Comment: Spot of code golf: the last term could just be '${var:6}'

Comment: Further golf : the first term could be just `${var::4}`

Comment: Thanks didn't think about either.  I did consider using `${var: -2}` for the last one but didn't want to lead to confusion.